# Bash script not quite matching

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to cat an apache log and then output the result to a file. I want to match the day/month with the Apache log to the current/previous date, however I seem to be doing this incorrectly.

Sample from apache log:
62.173.92.62 - - [02/Mar/2010:15:46:58 +0000] "GET /img.......

Current script:

```
cat access_log | grep "\[+%d+/%b" > email.log
```

Which I was hoping would match the `[0/2Mar` part of the line, however I am getting nothing in email.log (permissions are ok).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead, you need to call `date` and pass its output into the pattern. Also the `[` needs to be escaped.

```
grep "\[$(date +%d/%b/%Y)"
```

Comment: I would vote this up, but don't have any rep. Thank you- worked perfectly!

Comment: @aligibbs: You only need to be logged in to vote up answers - it is voting up comments and voting down that needs rep.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` doesn't work that way; it doesn't care what the current date is, it uses the regular expression you pass it blindly. Use `date` with an appropriate format to get the value you care about, and use that with `grep`.

Comment: That is, try `grep $(date +\[%d/%b) access_log`. (Note that you don't need the `cat`; `grep` takes arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
day=`date +%d`
mon=`date +%b`
grep "\[$day/$mon/" access_log
```

Comment: You can specify multiple placeholder with date, eg. date +%d/%b

Answer (score 0):

for current

```
grep "\[$(date +%d/%b/%Y)" file > email.log
```

for previous

```
grep "\[$(date +%d/%b/%Y -d 'yesterday')" file > email.log
```

No need cat.